# Object doesn't support property or method 'dataTable'; even with jQuery included

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have searched for this error, in the context of jQuery and data tables, and none of the suggestions worked (in case this is marked duplicate immediately!)

I have .Net project (C#) and in master page I have references to jQuery, Datatables and date picker (among other things):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-json/2.6.0/jquery.json.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.14.30/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link href="assets/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

In a page that uses the the master page I have a datatable and date pciker. I also try to set the modal pop up's title to be draggable. Using any of them causes "Object does not support property or method xxxx" error, where xxxx can be "draggable", "dataTable" or "datepicker".

I can't see why I get the errors when I am referencing jQuery. I even tried the ".noConflict" approach but it did't help either.

```
<script>
    function pageLoad() {
        $('#tbStartDate').unbind();
        $("#tbStartDate").datepicker({
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "../assets/images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonText: "Select Statrt Date",
            option: "mm/dd/yy",
            onSelect: function (dateStr) {
                $("#tbEndDate").val(dateStr);
                $("#tbEndDate").datepicker("option", { minDate: new Date(dateStr) })
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        j$(".modal-dialog").draggable({
            handle: ".modal-header"
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Load one jquery and related libraries first and then the other one. Those libraries are not aware that you've loaded multiple jquery

Comment: they are different libraries, no duplicates, and are added in order. It seems the main script (jquery) is not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
$(window).load(function(){
})
```

instead of document.ready.

Comment: $(window).load did not help. it is some issue with jquery not being loaded. I don't have duplicate references so it should work; i just can't see my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

In the "Scripts" folder of the project, I had jquery-1.10.2.js and jquery-1.10.2.min.js while in my master page I was referencing jQuery 1.12.4. Once I removed the 1.10 scripts from"Scripts" folder, the error went away.

Thank you nitsram and Brahma for taking time and responding; I up-voted your responses.